# Help reverting changes to GRUB

Tags: command-line, grub2, resolution

Okay, so I tried to use this fix for my blackscreen when going into tty command line

`sudo sed -i -e 's/#GRUB_TERMINAL/GRUB_TERMINAL/g' /etc/default/grub`

This did not fix it, but I found something else that did, but now I'm no longer able to change the resolution of tty command line, it gives me limited viewable lines and text looks blurry. I can't seem to find anyone with the same issue with not benig able to change it, so I assume the prior fix I tried using is what is now causing the issue since when I log in, (I dual boot) when I choose between windows or ubuntu, the resolution became very low for that after using that command. Here's my GRUB config file:
(had to upload a screeshot because apparently '#' make text very large?)

[image]

What I've tried so far is uncommenting and recommenting graphical terminal. If I remove nomodeset from the `GRUB_CMDLINE`s it gives me a black screen. Am I unable to change resolution if I have nomodeset in those lines?

Ok, so I changed monitors, and I'm able to change Grub's resolution again, but now I'm getting black screen again when I try to enter tty 1-6...

Answer (score 1):

To revert the change run

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/GRUB_TERMINAL/#GRUB_TERMINAL/g' /etc/default/grub
```

Or when you edit /etc/default/grub, just add a # to the GRUB_TERMINAL line.

Then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

The reboot

FWIW sed is a powerful command and substitues one sting for another, so all the sed command is doing is commenting out , or removing the comment (#) from the GRUB_TERMINAL option.

example :

```
echo GRUB_TERMINAL
GRUB_TERMINAL

echo GRUB_TERMINAL | sed -e 's/GRUB_TERMINAL/#GRUB_TERMINAL/g' 
#GRUB_TERMINAL

echo GRUB_TERMINAL | sed -e 's/GRUB_TERMINAL/#GRUB_TERMINAL/g'| sed -e 's/#GRUB_TERMINAL/GRUB_TERMINAL/g
GRUB_TERMINAL
```

the -i command edits the file /etc/default/grub in this case

Answer (score 0):

Comment `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` to `#GRUB_TERMINAL=console`.
Edit `GRUB_GFXMODE=1360x768` to the resolution of your monitor (it may already be the correct resolution). Update grub and reboot. If this didn't fix your problem, comment that `GRUB_GFXMODE` line out. You *might* have to sacrifice the grub menu resolution to use your tty's; I have had that problem before.

Comment: I am able to have it in low resolution, but from what I gathered NVIDIA drivers are the issue and there's no way around it unless you run it at low res, but thank you :)